# Programatically added button action not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am adding a static footer view in my TableView Controller via delegate method of viewForFooterInSection and it is working fine, and it is adding my required design like the way i want but action is not invoked on touchUpInside on button. I've went through stack and tried almost everything to no avail. what possibly could i be doing wrong. here's my code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let blackView = UIView()
    blackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 51, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 2)
    blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(blackView)

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 51)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 22)
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)        
    view.addSubview(button)
    return view
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 53
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

Comment: I just tested it on Playground and it works fine I get Button Tapped in console

Answer (score 1):

> Am trying to check your code its working fine addTarget will fired

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        let blackView = UIView()
        blackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 51, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 2)
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.addSubview(blackView)

        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 51)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 22)
        button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        return view
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 53
      }

      @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped working fine")
      }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful. Explain what was wrong and explain how this answer fixes the issue.

Comment: And how is this code any different? I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for the above question is here**

create a button action function into your class as `buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton)`
after adding button as subview of view assign action to the button as  `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)`    for details i have added code snippet below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let blackView = UIView()
    blackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 51, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 2)
    blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(blackView)

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 51)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 22)
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)        
    return view
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 53
}

func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful. Explain what was wrong and explain how this answer fixes the issue.

Comment: Ok sure, Thanks for your suggestion @rmaddy

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question? The question already has a valid selector and a valid matching button action method. All your answer changes is adding the `_` argument label to the `sender` parameter.  How does that fix the issue (hint: it doesn't)?

Comment: @GaneshManickam there's no need to add frame because the delegate method already returns a view and heightForFooter returns the height as well so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, I find the view frame having issue

add this line,

```
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 53)
```

So the code will be like this,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let view = UIView()

view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 53)

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let blackView = UIView()
blackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 51, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 2)
blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
view.addSubview(blackView)

let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 51)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 22)
button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)        
view.addSubview(button)
return view
```

}

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the selector in the question. This answer will not change anything. And this is a duplicate of other answers. There is not point posting duplicate answers.

Comment: can you check my updated answer?  **view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 53)**

Comment: I found that view is having no frame(widht-height), so its added with zero frame

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. It's working fine I just removed the `override` keyword from method definition since I am using Swift 4.0 and above. Please do check for below given things in your code as it may affecting your button click issue.

**1. Check whether any transparent view in not covering your tableView footer.**

**2. Check whether `userInteractionIsEnabled` is `false` for any view in the hierarchy.**

**3. Check for tap gestures if you have added any on view in that hierarchy.**

Answer (score -1):

All right, I have not get the points. Try to modify the two places:
1. *#selector(buttonAction)* -> *#selector(self.buttonAction(_ :))*. /
2. @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) -> delete the *@objc*
 **If there are not working, make the cell custom and implement the target action. It must be working.**

Comment: Do not post two answers. Edit one answer and delete the other.

Answer (score -2):

You selector name missing params, use  *#selector(buttonAction(sender:))*  to replace *#selector(buttonAction)*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the selector in the question. This answer will not change anything.

Comment: All right, I have not get the points. Try to modify the two places: 1.#selector(buttonAction) ->  #selector(self.buttonAction(_ :)) 2.@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) -> delete the @objc。 If there are not working, make the cell custom, it must be working.

Comment: Edit your answer, don't post comments. But there is nothing wrong with the method name or the selector.

Comment: My English is no good, if you could not understand what I say, just take more time~.

Comment: Again, don't post code in comments, put the information in your answer.